# Is there a function you can define in gdb to print the stack canary?

Tags: gdb, buffer-overflow

I was playing around with a stack buffer overflow on my x86_64 bit ubuntu VM, and I was wondering if there is a function I can define in my `.gdbinit` file to print the stack canary? My current process is breaking after the `mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28` instruction and then, after hitting the breakpoint, examining RAX for the stack canary but this is kind of annoying and I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: How do you compile the code?